# CSS overflow-y:scroll; missing something

Tags: css

i have one problem with CSS `overflow-y:scroll;`

I have created this **[DEMO](http://codepen.io/shadowman86/pen/pJeGeY)** from codepen.io

In this demo you can see there is a left sidebar. And inside have 11 `.layer` div . but if you scrolling down from the left sidebar then you can see only 9 layer other 2 layers staying inside.

What is the problem in my CSS. What i need to do for fixed it ?

**CSS**

```
.container {
  -webkit-animation: cardEnter 0.75s ease-in-out 0.5s;
  animation: cardEnter 0.75s ease-in-out 0.5s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  height: auto;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  max-width: 980px;
  min-width: 300px;
  margin-top: 75px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .06), 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0588235) 0px 1px 1px 0px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 0px 2px 5px 0px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  -o-border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  min-height: 140px;
}
.left{
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  float: left;
  width: 30%;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0px;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border-right: 1px solid #d8dbdf;
  -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 3px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius-topleft: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 3px;
  border-top-left-radius: 3px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
  transition: opacity 2s, width 2s, left 2s, font-size 2s, color 2s;
}
.left-header {
  -webkit-box-flex: 0;
  -webkit-flex: none;
  -ms-flex: none;
  flex: none;
  background-color: red;
  color: #fff;
  height: 108px;
  position: relative;
}
.left-list {
  z-index: 999 !important;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.9s;
  animation-duration: 0.9s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
  -webkit-animation-name: slideLeft;
  animation-name: slideLeft;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1);
  animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1);
  background-color:red;
}
.list-layers {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
.layer {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #f7f7f7;
}
```

Comment: The div for class="left" has the overflow set to hidden. If your browser view height is shorter than the height of that container, anything below it will be hidden. You can quickly see what I mean by updating the overflow for .left to 'auto' rather than 'hidden' OR reduce the zoom in your browser to 50% or so and you'll see more of the list appear

Comment: @SteveHynding Thanks for your answer. But i try it now please check my demo again. And the .left-header is not to be stay on there when i scrolling down. The green area is for the header.

Comment: @humble.rumble this is not a solution. Please see my [DEMO](http://codepen.io/shadowman86/pen/pJeGeY)

Comment: @humble.rumble also the green area will still be stay on there.

Comment: @SteveHynding i understood what mean but there is something wrong. Please see my demo again i need help about this regard.

Comment: @humble.rumble I want to make a scroll only from the `.list-layers` div. I need help only this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting `height: 100%` sets the element's height to that of it's parent, if there is another element contained within the div then it will not take that into account. You can change this...

```
.left-list {
  position: relative;         
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

To this...

```
.left-list {
  position: absolute;
  top: 108px;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

And it which means that it will start `108px` from the top of the containing block (or rather the closest ancestral non-static element) and end at the bottom of the containing block.

([Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZGewqY))

Answer (score 0):

change your `.left` class like this:

change `overflow: auto` to `overflow: visible` and `bottom: 0` to `bottom: 40%`

actually it should change into:

```
.left{
display: block;
position: absolute;
float: left;
width: 30%;
overflow: visible;
padding: 0px;
bottom: 40%;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
background-color: #FFF;
border-right: 1px solid #D8DBDF;
border-top-left-radius: 3px;
border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
transition: opacity 2s ease 0s, width 2s ease 0s, left 2s ease 0s, font-size 2s ease 0s, color 2s ease 0s;
}
```